# Why is angularfire auto-sync not recognized by angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am using angularfire 0.5.0 to set a scope variable called tokenRate in one of my controllers and displaying the value of tokenRate in the corresponding HTML file like so:

Controller:

```
function TokensCtrl($firebase, $scope) {

    $scope.tokenRate = $firebase(new Firebase("https://TEST_URL.firebaseio.com/token_rate"));

}
```

HTML:

```
<h1>Token rate is {{ tokenRate }}</h1>
```

I would expect the value to be displayed the first time and automatically update whenever "token_rate" is changed on the remote firebase. Instead, the tokenRate seems to be undefined initially and does not update when I change "token_rate" on the remote firebase.

The data sync is happening because I am able to receive "change" events from the remote firebase. I am guessing angularjs somehow doesn't know about the object change because putting a $watch on "tokenRate" doesn't trigger anything. I can get it to display the behavior I want by doing:

```
var value = $firebase(new Firebase("https://TEST_URL.firebaseio.com/token_rate"));
value.$on("change", function() {
  $scope.tokenRate = value.$value;
});
```

But this seems ridiculous to do every time. I don't think I am understanding something here. What is the proper way to set the $scope.tokenRate variable so that it displays the first time and syncs automatically?

Comment: Note that $firebase() will always return an object, even if the data stored in Firebase is a primitive. See the "Constructor" section on this page to see how to handle primitive values: http://angularfire.com/documentation.html

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out I'm new to this! So the proper way to do this would be to put in the HTML {{ tokenRate.$value }}?

Comment: Yes - use the $value property for primitives like string, integers and booleans.

Comment: Just for the sake of cleaning up your template a bit you should consider moving the Firebase specific code into a service, something like TokenRateSvc and have it pass back the tokenRate.$value object so your controllers / templates don't have to worry about Firebase specifics. This will also help w/ testability of your controllers.

Comment: @MikePugh I agree, I was just testing how things worked in angularfire.